# Is this an allowable question topic on this site?

Tags: discussion

I'm asking here in meta because it does not seem that chat is getting much attention here.

For the first time in my life I am in need of sending money abroad, through currencies and oceans.

Would it be appropriate if I ask here what options are available, what scams to look out for, and how to determine if a provider is trustworthy?

I am not looking to ask what's the "best" solution, I understand that's going to be my deliberation, I am asking for guidelines on how to determine if a service is trustworthy/good/won't be a waste of time and money.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally we prefer very precise questions for a specific situation. It sounds like you may be asking for opinions (although the scam warning shouldn't be that) on different options. Nothing wrong with that. But that's very likely to get close votes here. You could try Finance, but I think they too very much prefer precise questions.

Comment: I feel I am not looking for opinions, but for options. I understand that it is on my to make sure that the point gets across. I will think about it and see if I can formulate the question in an acceptable manner. thank you